# Submatrices of matrices in $\mathrm{SL}(4, \mathbb{Z})$ with all eigenvalues equal to $1$

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, matrices, eigenvalues

This is a follow-up question to my question from [Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4477214/976076) (Thank you Dietrich Burde and Michael Burr for the help).

Let $M\in \mathrm{SL}(4, \mathbb{Z})$ with all eigenvalues equal to $1$ (i.e. $M$ is a unipotent matrix).

Write $M=\begin{bmatrix}
A_1&A_2\\
A_3&A_4 
\end{bmatrix}, 
$ where the $A_i$ are $2$ by $2$ sumbatrix of $M$.

Let $d_i$ be the dot product of two rows of $A_i$, i.e. if $A_i = \begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d 
\end{bmatrix}$, then $d_i = ac +bd$.

Let $a_i = \mathrm{det}(A_i) - d_i$.

For example if  $A_1 =\begin{bmatrix}
1&2\\
3&4
\end{bmatrix}$,  then  $d_1 = 11$ and $a_1 = - 2 - 11 = -13$.

Consider the matrix $A =  \begin{bmatrix}
a_1&a_2\\
a_3&a_4 
\end{bmatrix}$.

**Question**: Suppose $A$ is in $\mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$, can one of eigenvalues of $A$ have absolute value bigger than $1$?

**Thoughts so far**: It is clear that the matrix $A$ should have all entries being non-zero. I find this question hard because two similar matrices might have differnt "behaviour", e.g.  if $
M_1=\Tiny\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \cr 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \cr 0 & 1 & -3 & 4 \end{pmatrix} 
$, then $
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \cr 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\in \mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb Z);
$
while if $
M=\Tiny\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \cr 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} 
$, we have $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, even though $M_1$ is simliar to $M_2$.

I also look up the [Block matrix determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices), but I don't think we can use the identities since our block matrices don't satisfy their assumptions.

Thank you for reading, any reference for this would be really appreciated.

Comment: This question has been answered in Stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

It is not a solution since $A$ is not in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, I will try to correct it later.

Let $a,b,c,d$ be in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ad-bc=1$.
Set
$$P = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
aI_2 & bI_2 \\
cI_2 & dI_2
\end{array}\right) \text{ and } T = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
I_2 & S \\
0 & I_2
\end{array}\right),$$
where $S \in \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{Z})$
Let
$$M = PTP^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
aI_2 & bI_2 \\
cI_2 & dI_2
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
I_2 & S \\
0 & I_2
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
dI_2 & -bI_2 \\
-cI_2 & aI_2
\end{array}\right),$$
Then,
$$M = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
aI_2 & aS+bI_2 \\
cI_2 & cS+dI_2
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
dI_2 & -bI_2 \\
-cI_2 & aI_2
\end{array}\right),$$
Since $ad-bc=1$,
$$M = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
I_2-acS & a^2S \\
-c^2S & I_2+acS
\end{array}\right).$$
Now, choose $S=I_2$. Then
$$M = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
(1-ac)I_2 & a^2I_2 \\
-c^2I_2 & (1+ac)I_2
\end{array}\right).$$
Hence
$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
(1-ac)^2 & a^4 \\
c^4 & (1+ac)^2
\end{array}\right).$$
and $\det(A) = (1-ac)^2(1+ac)^2 - a^4c^4 = (1-a^2c^2)^2 - a^4c^4 = 1-2a^2c^2$
and $\mathrm{Tr}(A) = (1-ac)^2+(1+ac)^2 = 2+2a^2c^2$.
If we choose $a=b=c=1$ and $d=2$, then we actually have $ad-bc=1$, $\det(A)=-1$ so $A \in GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and since $\mathrm{Tr}(A)=4$,
the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $X^2-4X-1$, so the eigenvalues of $A$ are $2 \pm \sqrt{5}$.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but I could easily have made a mistake. Can you say what you got for M and/or A?

Comment: @Paul Larson I give my computations. I also could easily have made a mistake, but I hope that it is correct.

Comment: Thanks, but $A$ is not in $\mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: @ghc1997 I had omitted this condition. I have modified the example, and I hope that it is right. I have a question: where does your problem and this transformation which replaces $2 \times 2$ blocks with entries a,b,c,d by a single entry $ad-bc-(ac+bd)$ come from?

Comment: Thank you for your time @ChristopheLeuridan, I also asked a similar question about replacing the 2 × 2 blocks by $ad-bc$. I thought I found some properties about the unipotent matrix, but people have provided counter-examples.